# Redis - ZRANGEBYLEX return empty set

Tags: redis

I have a set stored in redis like the following:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange my_set 0 -1
1) "ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044857"
2) "ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044858"
3) "ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044859"
4) "ABC20180108131627044830:XYZ20180108131627044830"
5) "ABC20180108131627044830:XYZ20180108131627044831"
```

They were added to the set using

```
ZADD my_set 0 ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044857
ZADD my_set 0 ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044858
ZADD my_set 0 ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044859
ZADD my_set 0 ABC20180108131627044830:XYZ20180108131627044830
ZADD my_set 0 ABC20180108131627044830:XYZ20180108131627044831
```

I thought I can use the following to get back all the item contains **ABC20180108131627044829**, but I'm getting an empty list here.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX my_set - [ABC20180108131627044829
(empty list or set)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your looking for an autocomplete behavior. Here's a `ZRANGEBYLEX` query that will give you only elements that starts with a string:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX my_set [STRING [STRING\xff
```

And for your example:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX my_set [ABC20180108131627044829 [ABC20180108131627044829\xff

1) "ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044857"
2) "ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044858"
3) "ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044859"
```

Note, all scores must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify partial values in the limits of the `ZRANGEBYLEX` command, you have to input an entire string, but you can take advantage of lexicographical rules.

This would work:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX my_set [ABC20180108131627044829 [B
```

As you see the beginning of the interval seems a partial keyword, but in fact it's not: for example, `ABCD` comes after `ABC` in these rules, and `B` comes after `ABC`, so you have to tweak your criteria to adapt to this.

Also, a reminder: `ZRANGEBYLEX` works only for members which have same sorted set score!

EDIT

```
ZRANGEBYLEX my_set - (ABC20180108131627044830
```

should work for your example

Comment: I also tried ZRANGEBYLEX my_set [ABC20180108131627044829  [ABC20180108131627044829, but it doesn't work, what's the problem here?

Comment: That criteria would only return the member with exact value, which doesn't exist.

Comment: It will return everything that "begins" with `ABC20180108131627044829` and is less than or equal to `B`.

Comment: `ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044857` is greater than `ABC20180108131627044829` so you can't specify `ABC20180108131627044829` as an upper limit if you want to list `ABC20180108131627044829:XYZ20180108131627044857`...